# How to use i18n translation in Vue 3 model file

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I would like to translate some strings inside my model and services classes in a Vue 3 app that uses the composition api. In Vue 2 I could use the export from VueI18n creation using `VueI18n.t`, but I do not know how I can do this in Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an example in this [lazy loading](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/blob/master/examples/lazy-loading/vite/src/i18n.ts) sample.

When you create i18n instance, you can export this instance, then in your model or service class, you can access it via `i18n.global.t`, which is the equivalence to the previous `VueI18n.t` access. Note, when calling `createI18n`, I exported this is `i18n` and imported this into my model and service classes.